# Set service-node-port-range in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

For our use-case, we need to access a lot of services via NodePort. By default, the NodePort range is 30000-32767. With **kubeadm**, I can set the port range via *--service-node-port-range* flag.

We are using Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster. How can I set the port range for a GKE cluster?

Answer (score 3):

In GKE, the control plane is managed by Google. This means you don't get to set things on the API Server yourself. That being sad, I *believe* you can use the `kubemci` CLI tool to achieve it, see [Setting up a multi-cluster Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress).

Comment: Hello Huy Hoang Pham, Were you able to find solution to update nodeport range? I am using costly service of type loadbalancer.